# Insert com select - Erro oracle ORA 00904

Tags: query, oracle, apex

Estou tendo dificuldade de entender o porque desse erro. Quero fazer a inserção  um campo {`descricao_posto`} na tabela `TB_POSTOS_NO_CONTRATO`, usando um select de outra: `TB_POSTO`. A 1a. tabela tem uma fk_posto que se refere ao id da segunda tabela, e ainda assim ele não reconhece. Alguma ideia?

```
INSERT INTO TB_POSTOS_NO_CONTRATO (DESCRICAO_POSTO) 

SELECT p.DESCRICAO FROM TB_POSTO 

where  TB_POSTOS_NO_CONTRATO.fk_posto = tb_posto.id
```

Mensagem de erro:

> ORA-00904: "TB_POSTOS_NO_CONTRATO"."FK_POSTO": invalid identifier

Comment: posta a estrutura das 2 tabelas

Comment: `TB_POSTOS_NO_CONTRATO "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, "FK_POSTO" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, "SALARIO_BASE" NUMBER(7,2), "DESCRICAO_POSTO" VARCHAR2(60), CONSTRAINT "TB_POSTOS_NO_CONTRATO_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") USING INDEX ENABLE ALTER TABLE "TB_POSTOS_NO_CONTRATO" ADD CONSTRAINT "TB_POSTOS_NO_CONTRATO_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("FK_POSTO") REFERENCES "TB_POSTO" ("ID") ENABLE `

Comment: `"TB_POSTO" ( "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, "DESCRICAO" VARCHAR2(150) NOT NULL ENABLE, CONSTRAINT "TB_POSTO_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") USING INDEX ENABLE,`

Answer (score 1):

Existem alguns problemas ai, o ID nem o FK_POSTO estão sendo referenciados no insert e como são campos not null, eles devem existir.
Para iniciar criaria um sequence para preencher o id da tabela TB_POSTOS_NO_CONTRATO, como descrito abaixo:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_TB_POSTOS_NO_CONTRATO START WITH 1;
```

E depois alteraria o sql deixando ele assim:

```
INSERT INTO TB_POSTOS_NO_CONTRATO (ID,FK_POSTO,DESCRICAO_POSTO) 

SELECT SEQ_TB_POSTOS_NO_CONTRATO.NEXTVAL,
       P.ID,
       P.DESCRICAO 
 FROM TB_POSTO P, TB_POSTOS_NO_CONTRATO PC

WHERE PC.FK_POSTO = P.ID;
```

Mas este sql incluiria uma possível inserção do ID da TB_POSTO que já existisse na tabela TB_POSTOS_NO_CONTRATO.

Exemplificando, se existisse a linha abaixo na tabela TB_POSTOS_NO_CONTRATO:

```
ID | FK_POSTO | DESCRICAO_POSTO
1  |    1     | null
```

Com esse sql, seria criada uma nova linha como a seguinte:

```
ID | FK_POSTO | DESCRICAO_POSTO
2  |    1     | "Descrição do posto"
```

Ficando a tabela com as duas linhas:

```
ID | FK_POSTO | DESCRICAO_POSTO
1  |    1     | null
2  |    1     | "Descrição do posto"
```

Para incluir a descrição em uma linha de um ID da TB_POSTO que já existisse na tabela TB_POSTOS_NO_CONTRATO, você tem que fazer um update e não um insert, como vemos abaixo:

```
UPDATE TB_POSTOS_NO_CONTRATO 
   SET DESCRICAO_POSTO=(SELECT DESCRICAO FROM TB_POSTO WHERE TB_POSTOS_NO_CONTRATO.FK_POSTO =TB_POSTO.ID);
```

A utilização deste sql seria a atualização da linha já existindo, apenas incluindo a descrição que existiria na tabela TB_POSTO.

Comment: Obrigado Bruno Cunha. De minha parte, houve um equívoco forte. Os registros já existiam então bastou o update. Para o insert seria necessário colocar os campos NOT NULL, mesmo. A sequence já existe e com o trigger . Resolvido, valeu!!!